# Warning: session_destroy(): Trying to destroy uninitialized session in D:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\MyBlog\lib\Session.php on line 27

Tags: php

when i try include with ../ at that time this error showing me.
**Warning: session_destroy(): Trying to destroy uninitialized session in D:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\MyBlog\lib\Session.php on line 27**

Admin login file location MyBlog/admin/inc/header.php

```
  <?php 
        include '../lib/Session.php';
        Session::checkSession();    
        if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == "logout"){
            Session::destroy();
        }
    ?>
<li><a href="?action=logout">Logout</a></li>
```

My Session File location MyBlog/lib/Session.php

```
<?php 
    class Session{
        public static function init(){
            session_start();
        }

        public static function set($key, $val){
            $_SESSION['$key'] = $val;
        }

        public static function get($key){

            if(isset($_SESSION['$key'])){
                return $_SESSION['$key'];
            } else{
                return false;
            }
        }
        public static function checkSession(){
            self::init();
            if(self::get("login")==false){
                self::destroy();
            header("Locaton:login.php");
            }
        }
        public static function destroy(){
            session_destroy();
            header("Locaton:login.php");
        }
    }
?>
```

Then i also try this :

```
 <?php 
    // include  ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/lib/Session.php');
    //include "../../lib/Session.php";
    include "/lib/Session.php";
    Session::checkSession();    
?>
```

Then its showing this kind of error:
**Warning: include(/lib/Session.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\MyBlog\admin\inc\header.php on line 4**

Comment: You should use a [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) autoloader and follow the PSR-4 standard. [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) is a good choice for this. This will avoid relative vs absolute path issues like this one

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php

Comment: sorry for late comment thanks all of you. My second problem path now solve but why my first error showing me

Comment: Trying to destroy uninitialized session in D:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\MyBlog\lib\Session.php on line 27"  but in my session.php file i initialize session_start() in checkSession() method and session_destroy are initialize in destroy() method. At that moment when i try 
 self::init() in destroy() method , then it show me this error " session_start(): A session had already been started - ignoring in D:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\MyBlog\lib\Session.php on line 4 " Now what is the problem.